# Constructing a closed interval from half-open intervals

Tags: real-analysis

Is it possible to prove (as elegantly as possible) that given an interval $[a,b]$ where $a,b\in \mathbb{R}$ are fixed, we cannot construct that interval from a finite intersection of half open intervals $(x_i,y_i]$ where the closed side of the interval is strictly on the right.

Note: this allows for the ability to take the compliment of an interval, e.g. to construct the interval $(a,b)$ using only closed intervals of the form $[x_i,y_i]$, we could use $(a,b) = [a,b] \setminus ([a,a] \cup [b,b])$

Comment: Finite intersection of closed sets is always closed - if you're happy to use that result?

Comment: The intersection of two intervals of the form $(a,b]$ is either empty or an interval of the same form. Hence the intersection of a finite number of such intervals is also empty or an interval of the same form.

Comment: To address the rather odd note: the complement of $(x, y]$ is $(-\infty, x] \cup (y, \infty]$. So, if you allow complements of such intervals, the result is a finite union of intersections of such intervals not allowing complements. The various answers provided easily extend to such a finite union.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you are given the intervals $(a_k,b_k]$, $k=1,...,n$. Let
$a=\max_k a_k, b= \min_k b_k$. If $a \ge b$ then the intersection is empty, otherwise the intersection is $(a,b]$.

Answer (score 0):

The intersection $I$ of convex sets is a convex set, so $(a,b]\cap(c,d]$ can be empty or an interval. If it is an interval, suppose WLOG $a\le c$ (if not, relabel). Now there are only two possibilities:
$$a\le c<d\le b$$
and
$$a\le c< b\le d$$
In the first case, $I=(c,d]$ and in the second, $I=(c,b]$.

Then, the intersection of finitely many of such intervals is also half-open.

Answer (score 0):

Let $(x_0, y_0]$ be the half-open interval such that $x_0 > x_i$ for all $(x_i, y_i]$ in your intersection. Then provided the intersection of all $(x_i, y_i]$ is non-empty, the interval that results from the intersection will have have $x_0$ on the left, and it will still be open on that side.